# New nested list from three lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have three lists.

```
x = {a,b,c,d}
y = {A,B,C}
z = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}
```

and I wish to construct the following list out of these three lists

```
{{a,A,1},{a,B,2},{a,C,3},{b,A,4},{b,B,5},{b,C,6},{c,A,7},{c,B,8},{c,C,9},{d,A,10},{d,B,11},{d,C,12}}
```

In the above list, every sublist or `z` is matched to an element in `x` and every item within a sublist in `z` is matched with an element in `y`.

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Transpose[{## & @@ Transpose@Tuples[{x, y}], Flatten@z}]
(* {{a, A, 1}, {a, B, 2}, {a, C, 3}, {b, A, 4}, {b, B, 5}, {b, C, 6},
    {c, A, 7}, {c, B, 8}, {c, C, 9}, {d, A, 10}, {d, B, 11}, {d, C, 12}} *)
```

or

```
Flatten /@ Thread[{Tuples[{x, y}], Flatten@z}]
(* {{a, A, 1}, {a, B, 2}, {a, C, 3}, {b, A, 4}, {b, B, 5}, {b, C, 6},
    {c, A, 7}, {c, B, 8}, {c, C, 9}, {d, A, 10}, {d, B, 11}, {d, C, 12}} *)
```

or

```
MapThread[Append, {Tuples[{x, y}], Flatten[z]}]
(* {{a, A, 1}, {a, B, 2}, {a, C, 3}, {b, A, 4}, {b, B, 5}, {b, C, 6},
    {c, A, 7}, {c, B, 8}, {c, C, 9}, {d, A, 10}, {d, B, 11}, {d, C, 12}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Thread /@ Thread[{x, {y, y, y, y}, z}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

returns

```
{{a, A, 1}, {a, B, 2}, {a, C, 3}, {b, A, 4}, {b, B, 5}, {b, C, 6}, {c,A, 7},
 {c, B, 8}, {c, C, 9}, {d, A, 10}, {d, B, 11}, {d, C, 12}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[Table[{x[[i]], y[[j]], z[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, Length[x]}, {j, 1, Length[y]}], 1]
```

> {{a, A, 1}, {a, B, 2}, {a, C, 3}, {b, A, 4}, {b, B, 5}, {b, C, 6}, {c,
>   A, 7}, {c, B, 8}, {c, C, 9}, {d, A, 10}, {d, B, 11}, {d, C, 12}}

Answer (score 2):

```
Riffle[Flatten@Outer[List, x, y], Flatten@z, {3, -1, 3}] ~Partition~ 3
```

> ```
> {{a, A, 1}, {a, B, 2}, {a, C, 3}, {b, A, 4}, {b, B, 5}, {b, C, 6}, {c, A, 7}, {c, B, 8}, {c, C, 9}, {d, A, 10}, {d, B, 11}, {d, C, 12}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
{Tuples[{x,y}],Flatten[z]}\[Transpose]/.{{x_,y_},r_}:>{x,y,r}
```